# Swipe to show additional buttons on UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to create a feature similar to tableView swipe to show delete button, the only difference is that I show multiple buttons and have it implemented on a `collectionView` within a `collectionViewCell`. I want to be able to slide the inner collectionView to the right and have multiple options buttons snap into view on the left.

Something like this:

[image]

I understand that I'll probably need to use `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, the problem for me is that the collectionView to pan is nested within another `collectionView`, and I'm not certain as to how to use the `UIGestureRecognizer` correctly so that the cells slide together and the buttons snap into view.

Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

set delegate in collection view for get action

```
protocol ColumnBookCellDelegate: class {

        func deleteBook(_ book: Book)
    }

class ColumnBookCell: AZCollectionViewCell{
     weak var deleteDelegate: ColumnBookCellDelegate?

     var canBeRemove: Bool = false{

        didSet{

            if self.canBeRemove{

                let swipeL = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.showDelete))
                swipeL.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
                swipeL.direction = .left
                self.addGestureRecognizer(swipeL)
                let swipeR = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.hideDelete))
                swipeR.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
                swipeR.direction = .right
                self.addGestureRecognizer(swipeR)

            }
        }
    }

// Show Delete Button
    func showDelete(){

        // unhidden button here 
        // self.button.isHidden = false
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) { 

            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    // Hide Delete Button
    func hideDelete(){
        // hidden button here 
        // self.button.isHidden = true
        // self.deleteButton.aZConstraints.width?.constant = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {

            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    // Delete Action
    func deleteAction(){

        self.deleteDelegate?.deleteBook(self.book)
        self.hideDelete()
    }
    // blob blob blob

}
```